# Who moved my view?

Tags: iphone, ios5, storyboard

Using storyboard ,I created a project.

Inside `viewDidLoad`,I did :

```
NSLog(@"%@",self.view.description);
```

I got :

```
<UIView: 0x8789cb0; frame = (0 20; 320 460); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x8789d50>>
```

But inside another XXControllerDelegate Method , I got :

```
<UIView: 0x8789cb0; frame = (0 0; 320 416); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x8789d50>>
```

I found the fact if I didn't choose `Resize View From NIB`  [image: Rise View From NIB]

I always got :
`frame = (0 0; 320 416)`

But I couldn't find anywhere resize the view from NIB.Who moved my view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view has `RM+BM` these anchors will be able to move the view y and x position in regarding to the parent view, when `viewDidLoad` is called the `superview` gets its size from the `xib` file, when `viewWillAppear` is getting called, the view will resize to the `superview`

If you want your view to not resize you should remove the `RM+BM`, check the screen shot

Remove the red horizontal and vertical lines in the right middle part of the image bellow

[image]

Comment: Thanks . It's helpful. Well...Why not any other frame ,but `frame(0 20; 320 460)` or `frame = (0 0; 320 416)` ?

Answer (score 0):

The frame of an `UIView` are relative to the superview it is contained within.

The bounds of an `UIView` are relative to its own coordinate system.

So you need to be sure where you are adding your view.